# Howto fade color of cell in GWT FlexTable

Tags: java, jquery, css, gwt, flextable

I am using GWT FlexTable to show numeric values.

If I use a Label label and setWidget(row,col, label) I can use gwtquery to fade the colors like this:

```
$(label).css("backgroundColor",color_from);

$(label).animate("backgroundColor:'" + color_to + "'", 5000, new Function() {
    public void f(Element e) {
    }
});
```

The effect is a nice fade from "color_from" to "color_to".

I would like to know how I can do this directly on the Tables cell, without having to create a Label for each cell where I want to use this effect. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

In your CSS file:

```
.myTableStyle td {
    background-color: #FFF:
    -webkit-transition: background-color 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transition: background-color 5s;
}
.highlighted {
    background-color: #F00;
}
```

In GWT:

```
table.addStyleName("myTableStyle");
table.getFlexCellFormatter().setStyleName(row, column, "highlighted");
```

UPDATED:

To do it in reverse order is a little more complicated:

```
.myTableStyle td {
    background-color: #FFF:
}
.backgroundEffect {
    -webkit-transition: background-color 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transition: background-color 5s;
}
.highlighted {
    background-color: #F00;
}
```

In GWT:

```
table.getFlexCellFormatter().setStyleName(row, column, "highlighted");
table.getFlexCellFormatter().addStyleName(row, column, "backgroundEffect");
table.getFlexCellFormatter().removeStyleName(row, column, "highlighted");
```

Comment: Cool solution, I was looking in the wrong place for complicated JS code and didnt think about how advanced CSS has gotten. This however reuires CSS3 but hopefully that won't be a major problem.

Comment: One additional question. This solution just fades in to the "highlighted" color. What If I want to go to red immediately, and then fade back to white?